# Unity - On Demand Resources IOS 13.4

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, on-demand-resources

Following this unity tutorial: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AppThinning.html

We are trying to use on demand resources for an app to fit the 200mb limit for the apple store.

- assets are tagged for the asset bundle
- asset bundle is built
- on demand resources are enabled
- xcode on demand resources are enabled
- appleconnect lists an asset pack
- testflight app works on our test phone (multiple build have been tested on this phone)
- ODR does not work on apple’s end for submission review ERROR: On Demand Resource request failed: The requested application data doesn’t exist

Current iOS that we have testing is 12.3. Xcode version 11.4. Unity version 2019.2.17

Could it be possible that the test iphone has the bundle cached and therefore does not encounter this error. Before every test, the previous build is deleted.

From the error it seems that the bundle is not being hosted. The test phone will be updated to 13.4 in the meantime, but it seems an important step is missing.

We have scoured the internet for a few weeks with no results, so if anyone has information, it would highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello! Please tell me, did you manage to solve the problem with On Demand Resources?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm experiencing something similar with my app. To give some context. I've embedded the Unity Engine (2018.4.9f) within a native iOS app (targeting iOS >11). Seeing as your experiencing this with a unity build I'm now not sure if it's an issue with Unity, Xcode, or Apple's backend (my money is on apple's backend. See: [recent ODR issue](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/129821)). My ODR works totally fine when tested locally and through testflight but gets rejected during app review because of a NSBundleOnDemandResourceInvalidTagError, meaning the tags my app is trying to access aren't in the tag manifest. It's been a serious headache because I can't replicate the issue at all. In the past I've eventually gotten builds approved after clearing the derived data and cleaning the build folder and continuing to submit until it works for them. I just submitted a build after completely uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling it to see if that might fix things. I'll keep you posted.